# Webpack bundle interface implementation depending on environment variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

In a TypeScript application that uses Webpack for bundling, we have an interface such as:

```
interface IMyInterface {
    method(): void
}
```

And two implementations which require different dependencies.

```
import IMyInterface
import package-for-foo;
class FooImplementation implements IMyInterface {
    method(): void { ... }
}
```

```
import IMyInterface
import package-for-bar;
class BarImplementation implements IMyInterface {
    method(): void { ... }
}
```

My idea is to have two different target bundles, one containing `FooImplementation` with `package-for-foo` dependency, and other bundle containing `BarImplementation` containing `package-for-bar` dependency.

Additionally, when running, the implementation of which `IMyInterface` would be used would be resolved at initialization (as it cannot change) and be a global variable accross the application, so clients could simply do `impl.method()` regardless of which implementation was initialized.

I am able to somewhat accomplish the running part by using an envvar and with webpack `DefinePlugin` creating a global variable. Then using this global variable at initialization to instantiate the proper implementation. After resolving the global variable, I'll do:

```
ImplControl.ts file

import FooImplementation from "./FooImplementation ";
import BarImplementation from "./BarImplementation ";

let impl: IMyInterface;

if (globalVar === "foo") {
    impl = new FooImplementation ();
} else {
    impl = new BarImplementation ();
}

export default impl;
```

However, they are all being bundled together still since they are somewhat coupled by the imports. Is there any way to make this happen as I want to?